# Book about five people who have magic powers, and at the start and end of each book there was a few pages of comics of stuff that happened in the book

Tags: story-identification, novel, magic

This group of five people have powers, and at the start and end of each book, there were a few pages of comics of stuff that happened in the book.

I know in the first book they are at a school dance possibly and there is a monster or bad guy trying to get them?

The main character has short red hair, and each character has a power of the element (i.e. earth, water, fire, air, can't remember what the fifth one is). At some stage, they find out that their teacher is a monster as well?

At the start of the first book, I know that the redhead main character and her mum move into a new town, and that's where the other four people are.

I feel it's something like *M.A.G.I.C* or something, but nothing came up when I tried to search it on the internet. I read it a while ago (like four or five years ago) but I think it was published in the 2000s? The title was definitely written like X.X.X.X.X (as in it had dots between each letter).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

*W.I.T.C.H.*, first volume of the book series (it's originally an Italian comic), "The Power of Five" (2004).

From [Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/591402.The_Power_of_Five):

> Will is new to Sheffield Institute, but quickly befriends Irma, Taranee, Cornelia, and Hay Lin, four girls with whom Will learns to share her mysterious supernatural abilities. Together they discover that they need to protect Earth from the evil of Metamoor. But things go seriously wrong for the girls at the school's Halloween dance when Metamoor henchmen crash the party and attempt to capture them. The girls have to command their newly discovered powers in their first battle against evil.

The fifth element is the "Heart" of Kandrakar, wielded by the protagonist Will, which can call the other elements to power.

[image: Pink cover, five main female characters depicted smiling]

---

Found by memory, I used to read these when I was a kid.

Comment: [What kind of lame power is heart anyway?](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/WhatKindOfLamePowerIsHeartAnyway)

Comment: Will can also turn machines into sentient, intelligent beings just by being near them.

Comment: Will's power isn't Heart.  It is Quintessence, the power of raw magic and creation.  The Heart is just the talisman she has.  Though initially her powers aren't as strong for reasons.